# Why irb not see the console module classes?

Tags: ruby

I trying to clone this app https://github.com/tomcat1911/mor, and when I trying run him from irb, shell show me an error

```
2.2.0 :007 > Mor::Application.new
NameError: uninitialized constant Mor::Application
```

but the module can be seen

```
2.2.0 :010 > Mor
 => Mor
```

What am i doing wrong? and where I read how to run such applications?

sorry for my bad English

Comment: Yes, IRB sees the module `Mor`, but evidently it did not find a class `Application` therein. (I see it should be there, however.) See what `Mor.included_modules` returns. Did all the `require`s load properly? Did it run properly from the command line?

Comment: I did it, and shell return me an empty array `2.2.0 :003 > Mor.included_modules
 => [] `

Answer (score 3):

You should run `rails console` to invoke console with rails app code. It will allow you to create objects of the classes, interact with the database etc..

 `rails console` is also nothing but an `irb` but app code and environment loaded in it.